# How to copy file from 1 server computer to another using xp_cmdshell with credentials

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

How can I copy file from 1 server computer to another using xp_cmdshell with credentials.I have an application server and database server.I want to transfer a file from data server to application server by executing the xp_cmdshell command  by using the network credentials of the application server. Iam using sql server 2012 and I have configured xp_cmdshell in the SQL Server.

I got "`Access is denied`" error when I tried to transfer file from my local computer to a specific folder in my shared network.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

It's a guess of course.

From [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) you can find that

> The Windows process spawned by xp_cmdshell has the same security
>   rights as the SQL Server service account

that means that this windows service account should have rights to the shared folder - which is not true I believe in your case.

So, to fix this you can specify a `xp_cmdshell` **Proxy Account** and then `xp_cmdshell` will execute commands under this specified account

Example:

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'SHIPPING\KobeR','sdfh%dkc93vcMt0';
```